# Difference between "zurzeit" and "bis jetzt"

Tags: difference, adverb

What is the difference between *zurzeit* and *bis jetzt*? Both in English mean *currently*, but I don't know if there is a difference in German.

If someone wanted to use them in a sentence, for example,

> Until now I haven't received anything

would both make sense?

Comment: Who claims that "bis jetzt" means "currently". I can't find any dictionary stating this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Zurzeit"

means something like "at the moment" or "right now"

> "Bis jetzt"

means "until now", which means the process has already ended.

Comment: "Bis jetzt" does not necessarily mean that the process has ended. "Bis jetzt ist das Wetter noch gut, aber der Wetterbericht sagt für heute abend Regen voraus". It means that a possible status change is expected.

Comment: 'up to now' might be a better translation.

Answer (score 4):

"Zurzeit" means right now, at this moment, presently, currently:

> Das Geschäft ist zurzeit geschlossen. The store is currently closed.

"Bis jetzt" means so far, until now, (not) yet.

> Bis jetzt haben wir das noch jedes Jahr so gemacht. Bis jetzt ist er noch nicht gekommen.

I don't think *currently* is a good choice to express that second case.

Comment: As a side note... shouldn't it be "zur Zeit"?

Comment: No, only zurzeit is considered correct, provided you mean "now": http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zurzeit"> Duden offers the following examples: sie ist *zurzeit* krank, aber sie lebte *zur Zeit* Karls des Großen

Answer (score 1):

> Zur Zeit = at this time
>
> bis jetzt = until now
>
> jetzt = now = currently

They are not the same.

> Zur Zeit --> At this time we don't know what the status is.
>
> Bis jetzt --> Until now nothing has changed.
>
> jetzt/momentan --> At the moment / currently / right now everything is working
>   fine.

Answer (score 1):

> would both make sense?

**No. You cannot use *zurzeit* here.** You'd use *Bis jetzt...* which corresponds *Until now*.

***Zurzeit*** denotes a current state, similar to ***derzeit, aktuell, momentan, im Moment, gerade, jetzt***

*One* difference between these is the usual period of time, this state continues. For instance in the two sentences

> Ich lege gerade einen Garten an.
>   Ich lege zurzeit einen Garten an.

the first one is about, that you are working on right now while in the second case, you are talking about a project which may take some days or weeks and you're not necessarily working on it right now.

The second point is, that such a state may change sooner or later. How it is understood usually depends on what you're talking about.

> Zurzeit schreibt sie selten Emails.

Maybe because, she currently has little time or whatsoever, but that state won't continue forever.